# Remover registro Mysql com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tenho uma página em PHP com conexão ao Mysql. Tudo funciona perfeitamente, porem tenho um botão DELETAR, que ao clicar nele, pega o ID daquela entrada, vai para uma página del.php e deveria remover esta entrada no Mysql. Porem, "parece" que ao clicar no delete, nada acontece. Se passar o mouse em cima do icone delete, ele retorna o ID de cada registro perfeitamente. Alguém pode me ajudar a entender o que estou fazendo de errado?

Código onde retorna os dados para a index.php

```
 <?php  
    while($row = $stm->fetch())  {




   echo "<tr>"."<td><input type=checkbox name='check[]' value='[]' ></td>"."</td><td>" .$row['ip']. "</td><td>". $row['hostname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['sender'] . "</td><td>" . $row['subject'] . "</td><td>" .$row['quantidade']. " <td><a href=del.php?id=". $row['id'] . " data-placement='top' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Delete'><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' data-title='Delete' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#delete' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></button></p>
</tr>" .'' ;
}


?>
```

Conteúdo do del.php

```
<?php

    // Dados da conexão com o banco de dados
    define('SERVER', 'xxxxx');
    define('DBNAME', 'yyyy');
    define('USER', 'qqqq');
    define('PASSWORD', '');

     if (isset($_GET['id']))
        $id = $_GET['id'];
     else
        $tmpString = null;


$opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');
$conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVER."; dbname=".DBNAME, USER, PASSWORD, $opcoes);

$sql  = "DELETE FROM spammer WHERE id=".$id;
$stm = $conexao->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Descobri o erro. Tinha uma TAG formulário em meu HTML que estava gerando este problema, removi ela e passou a funcionar.

Estou encerrando esta pergunta.

Comment: Uma observação: já que está usando prepare, use bind para passar o ID, e não concatenação. Dê uma pesquisada em "prepared statements" aqui mesmo no site para mais detalhes

Comment: @bacco, grato pela dica. Irei pesquisar sim.